# exclude images from “indexed_search” search results

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-indexed-search

I would like to exclude images from a search results with indexed_search plugin. I've excluded file types from indexing under plugin settings, but I'm not sure if that would also effect all images that were already indexed.

Comment: Might I ask, did you solve the issue and if so, how?

Comment: @twigmac, I've excluded them manually in Typo3 BE. There is a setting for exclude from index_search. Unfortunately I haven't found any other solution.

Comment: Thanks, [@ABoooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2269273)! I see. You mean the trash-bin button in the detailed statistics view? At least some way to control it.

Comment: @twigmac, https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/hriseo/stable/_images/img-4.png here's an image of what I meant. I can't remember anymore what exactly have I done, but I think this was it.

Comment: Thx, @Aboooo, you most probably excluded the whole page. In my case, there were images, which opened on click. Therefore they ended up as single image search results. The ️ worked but is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this setting only affects the indexing but not the search result.
So you need to remove all images that are already indexed - maybe it is easier to delete the whole index and rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: Thx, how can I delete whole index?